# AEM/CQ5 : Hide node from the sidekick menu

Tags: aem

I have a template node that I want to be active (cannot delete it), I just don't want it to be displayed in the siteadmin left menu.

I've tried **sling:hideChildren**; **sling:hideProperties="jcr:title"**, not helping.

So here is the CRX view

[image]

And this is what I want to hide in siteadmin#

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy - just add property **hidden** with boolean value **true** for **jcr:content** node of page - and it will be hidden in both tree and grid.